# Adding a border to the image of dimension 250*250 to make 400*400

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

from PIL import Image

import glob

image_list =[]

resized_images=[]

for filename in 
 glob.glob('/home/ayush/Downloads/data/cars_test_resized/250*250/*.jpg'):
           
            print(filename)

            img = Image.open(filename)

            image_list.append(img)

BLUE = [0,0,0]
for image in image_list:
  
 constant=cv2.copyMakeBorder(np.float32(image),75,75,75,75,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=BLUE)

    resized_images.append(constant)
    print(constant.shape)

for (i,new) in enumerate(resized_images):

    new.save('{}{} 
    {}'.format('/home/ayush/Downloads/data2/car_test/250*250',i+1,'.jpg'))
```

```
 AttributeError                           
ipython-input-27-e2b9d48c48db> in <module>
      1 for (i,new) in enumerate(resized_images):
----> 2     new.save('{}{}{}'.format('/home/ayush/Downloads/data2/car_test/250*250',i+1,'.jpg'))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: Are you using Keras to implement a CNN later?

Comment: The 'save' error happens because you're trying to save a numpy array as a .jpg. The .save method from numpy stores information as text data files, not images. In order to save as .jpg you need "graphics" libraries, such as opencv or matplotlib

Comment: You should use `cv2.imwrite('filename.jpg', img)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is trying to use a `save` method on the NumPy array.

You should instead use [**`np.save()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), so your line with the error is replaced by:

```
# Create file path
filepath = "{}{}{}".format('/home/ayush/Downloads/data2/car_test/250*250',i+1,'.jpg'))

# Save the numpy array
np.save(filepath, new)
```